# Read image size and hide watemark

Tags: wordpress, hidden

```
     <div style="margin:0px auto ;width:490;height:288px; overflow:hidden;"> // But here read and hide watmark on "height". 
  <img style="width:490px;height:318" src="******"/> // Original image src, and size.
  </div>
</div>
```

Me using wordpress, so i got uploaded images, and watemark on images at the bottom. I want to hide this 40px on botton.

Simple page: trollfesz.cc/fun/279887
I want to do same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the manual crop feature after uploading the image or if you want to bulk crop multiple images then use this plugin . I got the same problem hence resolved it with this plugin . [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/manual-image-crop/)

Comment: i need autoatice system(script) for make it resize same as on simple page. I just want to hide my watemarks same as on website.